# Pass Parameter Value as Where Clause in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to pass Parameter value as Where Clause in `SQL Server`. If I am passing values directly in Query, then It is showing me results but after using it with `SQLCommand` and `StorecProcedure`, It is not returning any value.

Please help me to solve this issue.
**My Query :**

```
Select top 15 UserId, (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as Name from tblUser Where  + @AllUserIds + (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE @Search1 + '%' AND (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Search2 + '%'

@Search1='abc'
@Search2=''
@AllUserIds=UserId!=2869 AND UserId!=1 AND
```

**C# Code :**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_Teacher_App";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Search1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Search2;

AllUserIds = "UserId!=" + AllUserIds.Replace(",", " AND UserId!=") + " AND ";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AllUserIds", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = AllUserIds;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = "GetUserSuggestions";
```

Comment: Parameters are not *replaced* to create the final SQL, so you can't just use things like `AND` or `!=` in the value, and expect it to change the query.  What is it that you are actually trying to do here?

Comment: I agree with @MarcGravell, seems like you're trying to build dynamic SQL using SqlParameter, this won't work. SqlParameter only replaces well defined parameters, this is to avoid SQL injection, but it seems like you're trying to do SQL injection to construct your query.

Comment: Also: if you are passing that in as command-text, that is **not** a  `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: Have you checked what is in the AllUserIds, Search1 and Search2 parameters you pass from the code? What is the resulting query string? Is it the string you would expect?

Comment: @MartinK., I have passed values as you can see in post. I have checked it using BreakPoint.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I have comma separated UserIds like 523,1,6985. And I dont want to repeat same ids in return data. So for that, I am trying to use dynamic Sql Query.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass a list of UserIds that you don't want to see in the results.  It's unclear what these are or how many there are, but perhaps you should think in terms of another column that you could filter on (isSearchable perhaps) instead of passing a dynamic where clause.  Or just get them all and filter out the ones you don't want once you receive them back.

Comment: @AllUserIds is varchar, so it should be @AllUserIds='UserId!=2869 AND UserId!=1 AND', right?

Comment: @MarkPeters, yeah, in the last I have that option only. After getting data, removed data from database which matches with list.

Comment: @MartinK., yeah, right.

Comment: Ok, let's assume you firstname is 'foo' and your lastname is 'bar' then your Where-Condition evaluates to: 'UserId!=2869 AND UserId!=1 AND foo bar' LIKE 'abc%' AND 'foo bar' LIKE '%%'. The first part evaluates to false because 'abc' is not the beginning of '@AllUserIds...'. Looks like you're trying to build dynamic SQL but that's not possible with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Complex queries involving flexible numbers of parameters are tricky. Fortunately, tools like "dapper" can help you here. It *looks* like you want to do something like the following:

```
int[] userIds = new[] {1,2,3,4};
var query = conn.Query(@"
Select top 15 UserId, (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as Name
from tblUser Where UserId not in @userIds
and (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE @Search1 + '%'
and (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Search2 + '%'",
    new { userIds, Search1, Search2 });

foreach(var row in query) {
    Console.WriteLine((int)row.UserId);
    Console.WriteLine((string)row.Name);
}
```

Note the things dapper does to help us here:

- clean parameterization
- parameter expansion of the `userIds` parameter
- result binding (`dynamic` in this case, but typed binding is also supported)

Comment: I am getting perfect result if i use cmd.CommandText but issue is when I am using Stored Procedure.

Comment: @JeetenParmar well... is it a stored procedure? because it doesn't look to be one, and you can't do what you are *trying* to do with a stored-procedure unless you use `sp_executesql`. Also, the code you have shown is simply **wrong**: it won't work as command-text unless you change how you are doing it.

Comment: @JeetenParmar by "command text", I mean: the exact query you have shown "My Query" as the `.CommandText`. That **will not work**: that query is simply broken.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be use a dynamic SQL to build a query in stored proc.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_Teacher_App]
    @AllUserIds nvarchar(100),
    @Search1 nvarchar(100),
    @Search2 nvarchar(100),
As
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @selectCols nvarchar(500), @wherClause nvarchar(300), @fromClause   varchar(50)
    set @selectCols = 'Select top 15 UserId, (Firstname' + '+ ' +  'LastName) as Name' 
    set @fromClause = ' tblUser '        --you can even pass this as  a param
    set @wherClause = @AllUserIds 
    set @query = @selectCols + 'from ' + @fromClause +  ' where ' + @wherClause 
    exec(@query)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score -2):

Try a few more brackets. If that doesn't work, remove all the where conditions and tyhen add them back in one at a time to help you diagnose where the issue stems from.

```
Select top 15 UserId, (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as Name 
from tblUser 
Where 
(
@AllUserIds + 
((FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE @Search1 + '%' )
AND 
((FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Search2 + '%')
)
```